# When a problem can be speeded-up using Blum's speed-up theorem?

Tags: complexity-theory

Here is the definition of Blum's Speed-Up theorem.

> Blum's Speed-Up Theorem. There is a decidable language A such that for every TM $M$ that decides A with running time $u(n)$, there is another TM $M'$ that decides A much faster with running time satisfies $r(u(n))$ such that $r(u(n)) \leq u(n)$ for any computable function r and for all but finitely many n.

Now, this theorem gives us a hint that we cannot reach to optimal algorithm for some problems.

Question: How do we know that if a problem can be speeded-up or not? For example sorting problem has a lower bound and upper bound that match, i.e. $\Theta(n \log n)$. Now, how do we know that Blum's speed up theorem cannot applied here and it might gives us a better running time than $n \log n$? I knew that the theorem says for some problems. So how do classify these computable problem or how do we know them?

Thanks

Comment: Blum's speed-up states that there *exists* a decidable language $A$ that can be sped up. You cannot apply it to a language of your choice.

Comment: I think you should be more specific, do you want an answer for question one or two?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Is it possible to know what are these languages that we can apply Blum's speed up theorem? Or in different way, what are these problems that we cannot apply Blum's speed up theorem? I'm not sure if this question is non trivial or not, but I'm just trying to understand the limit of this theorem if there is.

Comment: The languages that Blum's theorem applies to are artificial languages constructed in the proof of Blum's theorem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you. I have small question, Let A ba a language that we can apply Blum's speed up theorem to it. Then, we know that A doesn't have best algorithm. This implies that we don't have a well-defined time complexity. Now, can we say that if we don't have a well-defined time complexity, then this language is a candidate to apply Blum's speed up theorem?

Comment: Blum's speed up theorem only applies to very special languages. If you consider any language not particularly crafted to satisfy Blum's speed up theorem, it probably doesn't satisfy the theorem.